# SQL Parameter as part of a query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to use a parameter value as a part of query, like this:

SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE @PARAM

Where @PARAM = "ID = 1"

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible. But could you tell why you want to do this way? As long as sql statement is correct, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @query Varchar(max)

Set @query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' + @parameter

exec(@query)
```

i dont remember syntex but u can do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you just need to use dynamic SQL:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' + @PARAMS 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

**dynamic SQL has some downfalls that you should be aware of, if you wanna use it, read this article for more details:**

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: this could be another way. Thanks a lot to you too!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers appear to be more-or-less correct, but here's a complete example that you can try yourself:

```
/* We'll want two different variables--one
    for the query as a whole, one for the
    parameter.
*/
DECLARE @sSql VARCHAR(MAX),
        @sParm VARCHAR(MAX);
----------------------------------------------------
/* Build a temp table for demonstration ... */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #table
END
CREATE TABLE #table (
    [Id]    INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name]  VARCHAR(100),
    [Value] INT
)
INSERT INTO #table (Name, Value) VALUES ('Test1', 1)
INSERT INTO #table (Name, Value) VALUES ('Test2', 2)
----------------------------------------------------
/* Our complete query is some base plus the input
    parameter
*/
SELECT @sParm = 'Id = 1';
SELECT @sSql =
    'SELECT
        t.[Name],
        t.[Value]
    FROM #table t WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE ' + @sParm + ''

EXEC(@sSQL)
```